# Finding surface area of a shell by rotation of a ring

Tags: integration, geometry, area, 3d, surface-integrals

I need to find the surface area of a shell of radius R. to do so I assumed a circular ring of radius R being rotated by an angle π. How do I go about finding the area. My initial attempt was 2πr.rdθ where θ is the angle by which the ring rotates, but I have understood that this method is wrong as thickness rdθ isn't constant for every point on the circumference. How should I find the area?

I know there exist other methods too but please tell how do I go about finding area using this method only.

thanks

Comment: Are you trying to find surface area of a sphere?

Comment: yes spherical shell/sphere

Comment: Do you know of some formula for setting up this type of surface area as an integral? Are you trying to derive such a formula?

Comment: I know we could use shell method for finding surface area by rotating a curve around a specific axis, i was trying to find the surface area of the sphere on similar lines

Answer (score 1):

Consider a quarter circle $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ on $0<x<1$. Let's rotate this around the $x$-axis to get half of a unit spherical shell. We expect the surface area to be $2\pi$ (since we're taking $R=1$, and only half of the whole sphere).

If we slice the shell into thin slices, one may be tempted to simply integrate $2\pi y\,dx$ from $0$ to $1$, reasoning that we're adding up the surface areas of a bunch of rings the shell is made from. Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work. This slicing may work for finding the volume, but apparently this 'stair-stepping' of the surface (see (b) in the picture) messes up when calculating the surface area. So let's try refining this a bit.

Instead of approximating the curve of the sphere by making straight-across slices, let's use diagonal line segments (see (c) in the picture). This should make it more accurate.

[image: shell]

(I bet you're so jealous of my drawing skills :P)

Now, $$ds^2=dx^2+dy^2\implies ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}=dx\sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2}$$

Since $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, we end up with, uh... $$ds=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

Then, the surface area of (half of) the shell is $$\int_0^1 2\pi\,y\,ds=\int_0^1 2\pi\,\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=2\pi$$

Well, that was kind of underwhelming. But I believe that is how it goes.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I wasn't looking for this method. I clearly stated the method I was following and wanted answer along those lines only. assuming equation of the curve and then using method of shell is the method already known to me. nevertheless I am upvoting your answer but I won't be able to accept it for now.

Comment: Oh. I am so sorry for the misunderstanding